# How to hide/disable from showing a specific array in a list generated by php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PHP code:

```
<?
$shopsite_templates = array(
    array('tmpl_1', 'Template 1'),
    array('tmpl_2', 'Template 2'),
    array('tmpl_3', 'Template 3'),
    array('tmpl_4', 'Template 4')

);
?>
```

And a html and php code that created a list of those templates:

```
<? foreach ($shopsite_templates as $value) {?>
    <? for ($i = 0; $i < count($shopsite_templates); $i++){ ?>
        <div style="float: left;">
            <div id="reg_web_tmp_box">
            <div class="temp_name"><strong><? echo $shopsite_templates[$i][1]; ?></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="select">
            <div class="reg_selectradio"><input name="edittmpl" type="radio" id="tmpl_<? echo $i; ?>" value="<? echo $shopsite_templates[$i][0]; ?>"<? if ($formitems['tmpl'] == $shopsite_templates[$i][0]) { ?> checked="checked"<? }; ?> /> <? echo $langdata['registshop_temp_select']; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
    <? }; ?>
<? }; ?>
```

Everything is working fine, but I want for example tmpl_4 (template 4) not to be in the list. I cannot delete it, it must figure in $shopsite_templates but not in this list.

I need this because I have several Free templates that i offer to my costumers, and i have some templates that i dont want to offer them, but i need to use it for further business.

I hope you gurus will understand my question. Please help me!

Comment: Why not just check if $i != the index of the template(s) you don't want to include

Comment: or `if (!in_array($template, $hidden_templates_list))`

Comment: I didn't really got your point! (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have items you don't want displayed in array like this:

```
$hide=array(1,5);
```

And then in for loop just do:

```
<? for ($i = 0; $i < count($shopsite_templates); $i++){ 
        if(!in_array($i,$hide)){
         //echo your templates html or whatever
  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! This my first question here, and I didn't expect for such a quick and GOOD answer!